# Change class active with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, navbar, jquery-events

I have a html menu and I would like to change the active class when you click on a menu item.

**HTML :**

```
<nav>
     <ul>
          <li class='active'><a href='index.php'>Index</a></li>
          <li><a href='hello.php'>Hello</a></li>
     </ul>
</nav>
```

**Javascript :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $("ul li").click(function() {
                   // remove classes from all
                   $("ul li").removeClass("active");
                   // add class to the one we clicked
                   $(this).addClass("active");
                });
            }); 
</script>
```

It works but when the page finishes refreshing to go to the requested link, the class returns where it was by default (on the Index page).

Can you help me please?

Comment: You need to pass in some information so that it can determine which nav item should have the `active` class by default. You can set this class while rendering your php file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **localStorage** [this](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) article helpful for learning, try the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var find=localStorage.getItem("Menukey");
  if(find){
    $("ul li").removeClass("active").eq(find).addClass("active")
  }
});   

$("ul li").click(function() {
    localStorage.setItem("MenuKey",$(this).index())
   $("ul li").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
});
```